# Android Java Warning: get(String) in BaseBundle has been deprecated

Tags: java, android, bundle, deprecated

At "Bitmap tmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");" in the following I get warning: [deprecation] get(String) in BaseBundle has been deprecated:

```
startActivityForResult = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    if (data != null) {
                        // There are no request codes
                        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                        if (extras != null) {
                            Bitmap tmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                            if (tmp != null) {
                                encodeBitmapAndSaveToFirebase(tmp);
                                imageBtnRotateProfileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                imageBtnDeleteProfileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

Tried this too but also deprecated Bitmap tmp = (Bitmap) data.getParcelableExtra("data");

I know I should use a specific type-safe method, but how?

Comment: You should preferably be using a more appropriate Activity Result Contract such as `GetContent` btw - only use `StartActivityForResult` when there's no other built-in Contract **and** you can't make your own custom contract for whatever reason

Comment: "but also deprecated" - this is likely deprecated in Android Tiramisu in favour of the more type-safe variant that takes in the generic as a `Class` argument (`getParcelableExtra(String key, Class type)`) - so for example it would be `getParcelableExtra("abc", MyClass.class)` if you want it to be of type `MyClass`. You would then use the old API on <Tiramisu, or use the compat variant `BundleCompat.getParcelableExtra(Bundle, String, Class)` from the `androidx.core` artifact.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution as instructed by Edric**

```
if (extras != null) {
    Bitmap tmp;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        tmp = (Bitmap) data.getParcelableExtra("data", Bitmap.class);
    } else {
        tmp = (Bitmap) androidx.core.os.BundleCompat.getParcelable(extras, "data", Bitmap.class);
    }
    if (tmp != null) {
        encodeBitmapAndSaveToFirebase(tmp);
        imageBtnRotateProfileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageBtnDeleteProfileImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```